# pthread_mutex_lock __pthread_mutex_lock_full: Assertion failed with robust and 0x4000000

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex, assert

I'm working on a server-side project, which is supposed to accept more than 100 client connections.

It's multithreaded program using boost::thread.  Some places I'm using `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex>` to lock the shared member data.  There is also a `BlockingQueue<ConnectionPtr>` which contains the input connections.  The implementation of the `BlockingQueue`:

```
template <typename DataType>
class BlockingQueue : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    BlockingQueue()
        : nblocked(0), stopped(false)
    {

    }

    ~BlockingQueue()
    {
        Stop(true);
    }

    void Push(const DataType& item)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        queue.push(item);
        lock.unlock();
        cond.notify_one(); // cond.notify_all();
    }

    bool Empty() const
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        return queue.empty();
    }

    std::size_t Count() const
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        return queue.size();
    }

    bool TryPop(DataType& poppedItem)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        if (queue.empty())
            return false;

        poppedItem = queue.front();
        queue.pop();

        return true;
    }

    DataType WaitPop()
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);

        ++nblocked;
        while (!stopped && queue.empty()) // Or: if (queue.empty())
            cond.wait(lock);
        --nblocked;

        if (stopped)
        {
            cond.notify_all(); // Tell Stop() that this thread has left
            BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(BlockingQueueTerminatedException());
        }

        DataType tmp(queue.front());
        queue.pop();

        return tmp;
    }

    void Stop(bool wait)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        stopped = true;
        cond.notify_all();

        if (wait) // Wait till all blocked threads on the waiting queue to leave BlockingQueue::WaitPop()
        {
            while (nblocked)
                cond.wait(lock);
        }
    }

private:
    std::queue<DataType>          queue;
    mutable boost::mutex          mutex;
    boost::condition_variable_any cond;
    unsigned int                  nblocked;
    bool                          stopped;
};
```

For each `Connection`, there is a `ConcurrentQueue<StreamPtr>`, which contains the input Streams.  The implementation of the `ConcurrentQueue`:

```
template <typename DataType>
class ConcurrentQueue : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    void Push(const DataType& item)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        queue.push(item);
    }

    bool Empty() const
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        return queue.empty();
    }

    bool TryPop(DataType& poppedItem)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
        if (queue.empty())
            return false;

        poppedItem = queue.front();
        queue.pop();

        return true;
    }
private:
    std::queue<DataType> queue;
    mutable boost::mutex mutex;
};
```

When debugging the program, it's okay.  But in a load testing with 50 or 100 or more client connections, sometimes it aborted with

```
pthread_mutex_lock.c:321: __pthread_mutex_lock_full: Assertion `robust || (oldval & 0x40000000) == 0' failed.
```

I have no idea what happened, and it cannot be reproduced every time.

I googled a lot, but no luck.  Please advise.

Thanks.

Peter

Comment: What's the stack trace when it aborts?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comments.  I was trying to use GDB to get the stack trace, but another issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948113/boostweak-ptrt-lock-crashes-with-a-sigsegv-segmentation-fault] happens.  So I need to fix that first.  The difficulty I'm having now is that all these issues come from the load testing with 50 or 100 or more connections, and cannot be reproduced every time.  I will post more info once I have.

Answer (score 5):

`0x40000000` is `FUTEX_OWNER_DIED` - which has the following docs in the `futex.h` header:

```
/*
 * The kernel signals via this bit that a thread holding a futex
 * has exited without unlocking the futex. The kernel also does
 * a FUTEX_WAKE on such futexes, after setting the bit, to wake
 * up any possible waiters:
 */
#define FUTEX_OWNER_DIED        0x40000000
```

So the assertion seems to be an indication that a thread that's holding the lock is exiting for some reason - is there a way tha a thread object might be destroyed while it's holding a lock?

Another thing to check is if you have some sort of memory corruption somewhere. Valgrind might be a tool that can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found this post. It may be useful for some of you: in my case I was just missing the init.

```
pthread_mutex_init(&_mutexChangeMapEvent, NULL);
```