# Valgrind Makes All of My Program's Threads Sleeping

Tags: multithreading, sleep, valgrind

OS/Environment Info:

```
plee@sos-build:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:        11.10
Codename:       oneiric
plee@sos-build:~$ uname -a
Linux sos-build 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm working on a server-side project.

I have several issues with this projects:

1. [boost::weak_ptr<T>.lock() Crashes with a SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948113/boostweak-ptrt-lock-crashes-with-a-sigsegv-segmentation-fault)
2. [pthread_mutex_lock __pthread_mutex_lock_full: Assertion failed with robust and 0x4000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935665/pthread-mutex-lock-pthread-mutex-lock-full-assertion-failed-with-robust-and-0)

I was suggested to use Valgrind to find where the problem is (especially for the first issue).  So I'm using Valgrind.

`valgrind --leak-check=full --gen-suppressions=all --suppressions=valgrind_suppressions.supp MyServerSideProgram arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4`

My program has 13 threads running simultaneously.  At the beginning, they are working well. Unfortunately, after a certain amount of time, all threads go to sleep.

The command I used to check all threads' status:

`top -H -p [MyServerSideProgram's PID]`

And the result is:

```
top - 11:54:34 up 46 days, 22:30,  4 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.02, 0.05
Tasks:  13 total,   0 running,  13 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.5%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.2%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   9224140k total,  8135872k used,  1088268k free,   294988k buffers
Swap:  9431164k total,   424416k used,  9006748k free,  4973316k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                            
 8744 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:06.81 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8747 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:42.27 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8748 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  30:58.15 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8749 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:53.62 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8750 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  30:58.68 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8751 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:31.65 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8752 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:24.63 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8753 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  32:05.33 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8754 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:52.24 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8755 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:11.69 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8756 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:17.10 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8757 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  31:54.65 memcheck-amd64-                                                                                                                                    
 8758 plee      20   0 1379m 1.2g 6276 S    0 13.7  32:10.67 memcheck-amd64-
```

I checked the `man top`:

```
w: S  --  Process Status
   The status of the task which can be one of:
     'D' = uninterruptible sleep
     'R' = running
     'S' = sleeping
     'T' = traced or stopped
     'Z' = zombie
```

So any idea?  Thanks.

Peter

Comment: It's not clear why this is a problem. You don't tell us much about your code, but most likely all the threads are waiting for work to do. You can use `gdb` to attach to the process and see what the threads are doing. A `thread apply all where` command might help.

Answer (score 0):

As David Schwartz said,

> it's not clear why this is a problem

He is right.  I did a simple test: I created another separate client, and let it connect to the server, send commands to the server, and it got responses from the server.  So the server is in good condition.

That means, the load testing has some issues.  It just stops sending client commands to the server.

One of my co-workers wrote that part in Java (while my server is written in C++/Boost).  I need to look at his code.  It will take a lot of time.

I will get back here once I found something from the load testing code.

Comment: 'I need to look at his code. It will take a lot of time' - story of my life :((